# Two positively charged parallel infinite plates with different charge densities

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

There is electric field between the plates? How can I find it? And in this case, both plates attracts?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** The electric field generated by a charged plate with surface density $\sigma$ is

$$
E = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}
$$

pointing perpendicular to the plate. Adding another plate generates another field that adds to first one linearly